# Fazer uma função chamada soma_h para calcular e retornar o valor H com N termos onde N é inteiro e dado com entrada

Tags: python

Fiz o código mas não sei o porquê do output ser 1.

```
def soma_h(n):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        soma = soma + float(1//i)
    return round(soma, 2)
```

OBS: H = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... + 1/n

Comment: O operador // (floor division ou divisão inteira) sempre dará zero para qualquer denominador maior que 1. Creio que bastaria fazer: `soma += 1/i`

Comment: tente definir desse jeito: `soma = 0,0` para o valor não ser tratado como inteiro

Comment: Funcionou. O problema era // mesmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está precisando é implementar uma função para calcular a **soma dos inversos dos primeiros números INTEIROS positivos**.

```
def soma_h(n):
    soma = 0
    for c in range(1, n + 1):
        inverso = (1/c)
        soma += inverso
    return round(soma, 2)


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(soma_h(num))
```

Observe que quando executamos o código nos é passado a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar `enter`. A partir deste momento o código irá calcular o **somatório** dos **inversos** de **1** até **n**.

**Testando o código:**

Se quisermos calcular a soma dos **inversos dos n primeiro inteiros** teríamos:

```
n = 2 = (1/1) + (1/2) = 1.50
n = 3 = (1/1) + (1/2) + (1/3) = 1.83
n = 4 = (1/1) + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) = 2.08
```

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão por **List Comprehensio** seria:

```
def soma_h(n):
    return round(sum([(1/x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]), 2)


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(soma_h(num))
```